# Calculate an Average from user input of five to ten numbers using Methods

Tags: java

My assignment requires me to prompt a user for 5 to 10 numbers and then calculate the average of those numbers. I also have to use methods to do so. My question is, how do I get the program to calculate the average if exactly if I'm not sure if they will enter 5 or 10 numbers? Below is what I have so far, I'm also having a little trouble understanding how to get the methods to execute in the main method but I think I have the actual method ideas right.

It was suggested that I format as reflected below, but my problem here is that it does not print anything after the user inputs its numbers, can anyone see what I'm missing? I'm thinking maybe I did something wrong in the main method?

```
public class AverageWithMethods {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String userNumbers = getUserNums();
        double average = userNumAvg(userNumbers);
        printAverage(0, userNumbers);

    }

    public static String getUserNums() {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String userNumInput = "";
        System.out.print("Please enter five to ten numbers separated by spaces: ");
        userNumInput = in.nextLine();
        return userNumInput;
    }

    public static double userNumAvg(String userNumInput) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner line = new Scanner(in.nextLine());
        
        double count = 0;
        double average = 0.0;
        double sum =0;
        

        while (in.hasNextDouble()) {
            count++;
            sum = line.nextDouble();

        }
        if (count != 0) {
            average = sum / count;
            count = Double.parseDouble(userNumInput); 
        }
        
        return average;
    }

    public static void printAverage(double average, String userNumInput) {
        System.out.printf("The average of the numbers " + userNumInput + " is %.2f", average);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your first section of code I am making the assumption all the numbers are entered on a single line all at once.

> My question is, how do I get the program to calculate the average if exactly if I'm not sure if they will enter 5 or 10 numbers?

The `Scanner` object you are using has a method [`hasNextInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt()) so you can construct a simple `while` loop to figure out how many numbers there are.

```
Scanner line = new Scanner(in.nextLine()); // Feed line into scanner
int numbers = 0;
double total = 0.0;
while(in.hasNextInt()) { // read all the numbers
    numbers++;
    total += line.nextDouble();
}
line.close(); // Good habit
```

You can then compute your average with all this information:

```
double avg = total/numbers;
```

**Notes:**

- Making `total` a double to avoid integer math when computing the average. There are obviously other ways to avoid integer math and I can include more if you would like.
- I use a second `Scanner` with a `String` parameter of `in.nextLine()` because if you skip that step, the code won't terminate when reading a continuous input stream such as a console/terminal. This is because there will be a next int possible since the terminal is still accepting input.

Comment: that's correct, they are to be entered all at one line. I added the Scanner you suggested but it's coming up with an error  "cannot find symbol". This is supposed to go under the userAvg method correct?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to provide this as a cut-and-paste solution to your problem rather a very very similar example. You can pass into the new Scanner `userNumInput`. `Scanner line = new Scanner(userNumInput)`.. However, I would recommend trying to understand the code rather than just cut and pasting it.. I'm more than willing to answer any and all questions you have about the code :)

Comment: Thanks, I did change the words (ie you use total while I use sum in the above) I think the second scanner is something I don't quite understand as well especially placing it within a while statement.

Comment: Okay great :) So the `Scanner` object can take a string argument just as it would take `System.in`, then everything you would normally do on a `Scanner(System.in)` can be done on a `Scanner(String)`. The reason I place it within the while loops is so that this pattern is satisfied - `while(<condition> == true) { <do Stuff> }`. The condition here is `line.hasNextInt()` which does exactly as you would expect (I linked the java docs in the answer, check them out). This loop will run until there are no more integers to read, aka the end of the line

Comment: I really appreciate your not only helping but further explaining the reasoning. That really helps! The only other question I have, in order to have this execute, how do I place a double method in the main? For this code, I can simply place getUserNums(); in the main and it print what I want, but the userAvg method is giving me an issue... am I to use the while statement in the main instead of the userAvg?

Comment: You should be able to call `userAvg(userNumInput)` once from your main. With the code I gave you and the change we discussed inside userAvg

Comment: @Steph78 if this solved your problem please make sure to mark it as the accepted answers for others that may have a similar issue :)

Comment: additional question:

how do I make this as a double? instead of in.HasNextLine I need to user .hasNextDouble but I keep getting an error that it cannot find symbol?

Comment: Scanner line = new Scanner(in.nextLine()); // Feed line into scanner
int numbers = 0;
double total = 0.0;
while(in.hasNextInt()) { // read all the numbers
    numbers++;
    total += line.nextInt();
}
line.close(); // Good habit

Comment: instead of replacing the `in.nextLine()` replace `line.nextInt()` with `line.nextDouble()`

Answer (score 1):

count how many spaces there are in your string.  You can do this either by looping and checking the char value or you can do a replace on the string and compare the size of the new String

e.g.

```
    String fiveNums = "1 2 3 4 5";
    String noSpaces = fiveNums.replace(" ", "");
    System.out.println(fiveNums.length() - noSpaces.length());
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to understand how many numbers input the user, you can:

```
String[] userNumInput = in.nextLine().split(" ");
int quantity = userNumInput.length;
```

User input `quantity` numbers.

Here is one of the possible ways to do from your original code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GetAverage {

    public GetAverage() {
        String getStr = getUserNums();
        double result = userAvg(getStr);
        printAverage(result, getStr);

    }

    public String getUserNums() {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter five to ten numbers separated by spaces: ");
        return in.nextLine();
    }

    public static double userAvg(String str) {
        String[] arr = str.split(" ");
        double sum = 0.0;
        double average = 0.0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            sum += Integer.parseInt(arr[i]);
        }
        if (arr.length > 0) {
            average = sum / arr.length;
        }

        return average; // how do I get the program to count what to divide by since user can input 5- 10?
    }

    public static void printAverage(double average, String userNumInput) {
        System.out.printf("The average of the numbers " + userNumInput + "is %.2f", average);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GetAverage();

    }
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Please enter five to ten numbers separated by spaces: 
5 7 8 9 6 3 2 4
The average of the numbers 5 7 8 9 6 3 2 4is 5.50
```

Comment: Could you please explain what changes you made and why? Code dumping isn't a great answer

Comment: why do you bother creating a new `int array` - as you are already looping why not just sum?

Comment: I wanted to be closer for the original code. Yes, you're right, I need to optimize the code